# Get character after last underscore in awk "if" statement

Tags: awk

I have csv with sample data below.

```
column1,column2,column3
abc,123,sample_test_FT.txt
abc,123,sample_test_IFT.txt
```

I need to print only the lines whose character after the last underscore of column 3 is equals to "I"

desired output:

```
column1,column2,column3
abc,123,sample_test_IFT.txt
```

I've come up with this code so far but doesn't quite work.

```
awk -v FPAT='([^,]*)|("[^"]*")' -v var1=3 '{if (substr("${var1##*_}",1,1) == "I" ) print; else TRUE}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk -v FPAT='([^,]*)|("[^"]*")' 'NR==1; NR>1 && match($3,"_I[^_]*$")'
```

The regular expression checks for presence of `_I` and that there are no more underscores in `$3`.

Comment: Thank you this works great! what if i want the opposite? If i want to print those without _I?

Comment: @user2058738 just add an exclamation sign (`!`) before `match`. That is the logical negation operator.

Answer (score 0):

With **`awk`**'s `match()` function:

```
awk -v FPAT='[^,]+|"[^"]+"' 'NR==1; NR > 1 && match($3, /^[^_]+_[^_]+_I/)' file
```

The output:

```
column1,column2,column3
abc,123,sample_test_IFT.txt
```

Comment: Thank you. However this doesnt  work if value of column 3 has more than 2 underscores. eg. sample_test_123_IFT.txt. But this is more than enough to guide.